# What is wrong with this basic algebra/trig that I'm doing?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

I have to solve for $x$:

$e^{x\sqrt3}(3cos(3x)+\sqrt3sin(3x))=0$

So $3cos3x+\sqrt3sin3x=0$

Divide through by$cos3x$:

$3+\sqrt3tan3x=0$

$tan3x=-\dfrac{3}{\sqrt3}$

$\therefore$   $3x=-\dfrac{\pi}{3}$

$\therefore$ $x=-\dfrac{\pi}{9}$

However, that's wrong and I can't see where I'm going wrong. I must be making a silly error, can you help me identify it?

Comment: You got one of the solutions, there are many others.

Comment: But when I plug my solution in it doesn't equal 0

Comment: Maybe your calculator is set to degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions of the equation $\tan 3x = -\frac{3}{\sqrt{3}}$ can be written in the form $3x=-\frac{\pi}{3}+k\pi$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore $x=-\frac{\pi}{9}+k\frac{\pi}{3}, k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

What is the correct solution in your textbook?

Comment: The correct solution is 2pi/9

Comment: Your correct solution is only one of infinitely many correct solutions $x=-\frac{\pi}{9}+k\frac{\pi}{3}, k \in \mathbb{Z}$. You can obtain it by substitution $k=1$. Look to your textbook, maybe there are some conditions for your solution, for example "find the first positive solution of the equation ..." or something like this. However generaly trigonometric equations have infinitely many solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is *one* solution; but you stopped too early.

Recall that trigonometric functions are not injective; indeed, they are periodic, and so there are infinitely many $x$ such that $3x= -\frac{\pi}{3}$.

We can expand on your solution to $3x$ by noting that if $3x = -\pi/3$ is true, then so is $$3x = -\pi/3 + k\pi, \;k\in \mathbb Z, \;\text{and so}\; x = -\dfrac{\pi}{9} + \frac{k\pi}{3}\;\text{ for any} k\in \mathbb Z$$